# Entity properties as string names in EF Core queries and CRUD, how to achieve without expressions?

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-8.0

I have a TPT hierarchy based on a `Product` entity that has many derived entities representing different product categories and their attributes as column names and attribute values as column values. This is a recommended scheme I read in some posts in StackOverflow.

Now I face a challenge, I can obtain column names for each category table with a simple query. The problem is, I want to use these string column names in many different queries and CRUD operations, and some queries are very complex and made by using LinqKit.Core package.

I saw simple solutions for using entity properties as strings using expressions in this site.

But the problem is using these solutions makes queries that are already complex, much more complex.

So my question: is there any simpler solution, something like:

```
Where(e => e.Field<string>("EntityProperty")
```

or any nuget package that expose a better and simpler way to do this other than using expressions?

Comment: `EF.Property<string>(e, "EntityProperty")` ?

Comment: *This is a recommended scheme I read in some posts in StackOverflow* -- Probably because some people have a primeval fear for EAV. But this seems to me a perfect case for EAV. To me it doesn't make sense to have to add a new derived entity to your code base when a new category is concocted (and maybe even new columns when new attributes appear). It's not flexible at all. It also doesn't allow a product to fall into multiple categories. I don't say that EAV doesn't have problems, but IMO less than this TPT setup.